# Clear several conditions, in different moments, before executing

Tags: javascript, jquery, conditional-statements

I am looking for a common pattern or method to accomplish the following:

> A server sends messages to a (browser) client. These messages do NOT arrive alltogether, but in different moments in time.
>
> For each incoming message the client compares it with a list of conditions. If message matches condition, that condition is satisfied.
>
> Once all conditions are satisfied, the client executes some orders, and moves to the next set of conditions.
>
> This is repeated until all sets of conditions available are satisfied.

My actual approach to this problem is the following:

A set of nested arrays contain the sets of conditions, and the equivalent actions to perform when each set of conditions is satisfied. For example:

```
var condAct = 
[
  [ // set 0
    [ // conditions
      "condition 1", "condition 2"
    ],
    [ // actions
      action, action2
    ]
  ],
...
```

A variable keeps the number of the actual set of conditions.

```
var condStep = 0;
```

A single function is triggered when a message arrives. It compares the incoming message with all the conditions in the actual step. If the message matches a condition, the condition is removed from the array. Once all conditions on this step are satisfied, and so removed from the array, actions are executed, and we move to the next step:

```
function condRcv(msg){
  for (var i = 0; i < condAct[condStep][0].length; i++) { // for each condition in the actual set
    if(msg === condAct[condStep][0][i]){ // if it matches the incoming message
      condAct[condStep][0].splice(i, 1); // remove the condition from the array
      if(condAct[condStep][0].length === 0){ // and if the actual conditions array is already empty
        for(var j = 0; j < condAct[condStep][1].length; j++){ // for each action in the actions array
          condAct[condStep][1][j]; // execute it
          condStep++; // up a step 
          return; // get outta here
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My approach seems initially valid, but a bit convoluted, both the procedure and the code.

Is there a commonly used pattern or method, in js or even jquery to solve a situation like this?

Thanks. 
Let me know if you think I can improve the question.

Comment: Yes...the common pattern is to use array of promises and pass that array to Promise.all() and within callback you will have the responses in same order as they were sent. If using jQuery as tagged can use `$.when()` instead of `Promise.all()`

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks for the answer. Although I've been reading about it, I do not fully understand promises. Care to write a detailed answer so I could accept it?

Comment: are these ajax requests you are making?

Comment: @charlietfl no, I am using "sillyserver" ( https://github.com/jagenjo/SillyServer.js ) to send messages between connected clients. This messages refer to start and end of speech synthesis or recognition (web speech api). I am building some sort of conditional score, that involves synthesis and recognition for several clients.  For example, before clients 2 and 3 start synthesizing speech, I need to make sure they have finished recognizing speech, and that client 1 has finished synthesizing speech aswell. This sort of thing.

Comment: More practically there is a function that receives the messages sent by other clients, and I can place other functions within this one. server.on_message = function( author_id, msg ){ //myfunctions };

Comment: ok...so you can't loop through a series of requests at one time...you need to send then wait for response. So rather than array of promises...you would need a promise chain. You send something...when `server.on` comes back with matching message...that would resolve first promise which is chained using `then()` to do nest step. You can chain as many `then()` as is needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilize `.queue()`, `.promise()`, `.then()`

```js
var q = $({});

var queueName = "conditions";

var arr = [1,2,4,4,5];

var conditions = [2,3,4,5,7];

var results = [];

var fn = function (prop, next) {
  console.log(prop);
  results.push(prop);
  next();
}

q.queue(queueName, $.map(arr, function(curr, index) {
  return function(next) {
    return curr + 1 === conditions[index] 
           ? fn(curr + 1 + " equals " + conditions[index], next) 
           : /* do other stuff here, pass `next` function, call `next` */ 
             fn("curr plus 1 does not equal " + conditions[index], next)
  }
}));

var promise = q.dequeue(queueName).promise(queueName);

promise
.then(function() {
  console.log("complete", results);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```